# Are there any standard functions to iterate across predicates by applying to single value?

Tags: common-lisp, higher-order-functions

There are always many functions for iterating across list of values like `mapcar`, `every`, `some`.

I need iteration across predicates for single value:

```
(let ( (val (complex-expr ...)) )
   (or (pred1 val) (pred2 val) ... (predN val)))

(let ( (val (complex-expr ...)) )
   (and (pred1 val) (pred2 val) ... (predN val)))
```

Are there any standard functions doing above code with syntax:

```
(some-p val pred1 pred2 ... predN)
(every-p val pred1 pred2 ... predN)
```

**UPDATE** FYI [Elisp have this function in it's standard  library](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16756/is-there-a-standard-function-that-applies-a-list-of-predicates-to-a-value-until):

```
run-hook-with-args-until-success
run-hook-with-args-until-failure
run-hook-with-args
```

Comment: argument lists have a limited length. See the variable CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT, which must be 50 (!) or larger. That means, in some implementation it might be only 50.

Comment: Thus, if you work with lists, then pass them as arguments and don't use the argument list for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard doesn't include anything exactly like what you're asking for, but it does include **some** and **every** for computing **(or (f x1) (f x2) … (f xn))** and **(and (f x1) (f x2) … (f xn))**:

```
CL-USER> (some 'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5))
T
CL-USER> (every 'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5))
NIL
```

What you're trying to do fits into this paradigm, except that the **f** you need should take each **x<sub>i</sub>**, treat it as a function, and call it with some value.  **Some** and **every** still work here:

```
CL-USER> (let ((value 3))
           (some (lambda (predicate) (funcall predicate value)) '(evenp symbolp oddp)))
T
CL-USER> (let ((value "hello"))
           (some (lambda (predicate) (funcall predicate value)) '(characterp numberp)))
NIL
```

Of course, you can wrap that up another in function to avoid writing the lambda function every time:

```
(defun some-p (value predicates)
  (some (lambda (predicate)
          (funcall predicate value))
        predicates))
```

```
CL-USER> (some-p "hello" '(characterp numberp))
NIL
CL-USER> (some-p 3 '(characterp numberp))
T
```

If you really want the function to variadic (like you showed in your question), you can do it with a **&rest** parameter, but do note that it's not the style most of these kinds of functions use:

```
(defun some-p (value &rest predicates)
  (some (lambda (predicate)
          (funcall predicate value))
        predicates))
```

```
CL-USER> (some-p 3 'characterp 'numberp)
T
CL-USER> (some-p "hello" 'characterp 'numberp)
NIL
```

It's much more common to take the arguments as a list, though.  Two good reasons for this (which are part of the same phenomenon) are that: (i) it's easier to pass the list from another source.  E.g., it's easier to do **[a]** than **[b]**:

```
(let ((preds '(p1 p2 ... pn)))
  (some-p-list value preds)           ; [a]
  (apply 'some-p-rest value preds))   ; [b]
```

Even if you don't mind the **apply** in **[b]**, as [Rainer Joswig noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671159/are-there-any-standard-functions-to-iterate-across-predicates-by-applying-to-sin/32671630#comment53200136_32671159) [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671159/are-there-any-standard-functions-to-iterate-across-predicates-by-applying-to-sin/32671630#comment53200210_32671159), there's a constant **call-arguments-limit** in a Common Lisp implementation that puts a limit on the number of arguments a function can be called with.  It's often big, but it can be as small as 50.  That means that if **preds** has 50 elements, then **(apply 'some-p-rest value preds)** would fail.

Comment: I don't know about tradition to use list instead of variadic, thanks for answer +1

Comment: @gavenkoa It's not often *mentioned*, I guess, but I bet that you're actually familiar with it.  After all, you knew that you'd do `(mapcar (lambda (x) (* x 2)) '(1 2 3 4 5 6))` and not `(mapcar (lambda (x) (* x 2)) 1 2 3 4 5 6)`.  It's not a hard and fast rule, but if you had the list of predicates coming in from somewhere else and you use **&rest** parameters, you'd have to do **apply**;  e.g., `(let ((ps '(p1 p2 p3))) (apply 'some-p value ps))`.  If you take the list as a single argument, you can do `(let ((ps '(p1 p2 p3))) (some-p value ps))`.

Comment: ABCL's CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT = 50. LispWorks = 2047.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard function, but it is easy to write:

Note that you can also use the `LOOP` macro for that:

**some**

```
CL-USER 10 > (loop with value = 4
                   for pred in (list #'numberp #'plusp #'oddp)
                   thereis (funcall pred value))
T
```

**every**

```
CL-USER 11 > (loop with value = 3
                   for pred in (list #'numberp #'plusp #'oddp)
                   always (funcall pred value))
T
```

**every-p**

```
CL-USER 16 > (defun every-p (value predicates)
               (loop for predicate in predicates
                     always (funcall predicate value)))
EVERY-P

CL-USER 17 > (every-p 3 (list #'numberp #'plusp #'oddp))
T
```

Comment: One goal in question is to eliminate `let` binding so *complex-expr* evaluates only once. This can be done by macro or function call or may be some other method.

Comment: @gavenkoa In **(loop with value = *complex-expr* ...)**, the *complex-expr* is only evaluated once.

Comment: Now this is full answer. Thanks! Elisp `cl-loop` support such syntax too.